# Complexheatmap row boxes or grids are not visible

Tags: r, complexheatmap

I would like to see each row like this looking distinct grid

Such as this
[image: this image]

This is my code which im running

```
Heatmap(heat, col = col_fun,name="Z-score", 
        show_row_names = TRUE, show_column_names = TRUE, cluster_rows = FALSE,
        cluster_columns = FALSE, show_column_dend = TRUE, show_row_dend = FALSE,
        column_title="Samples",
        column_title_side="top",
        row_names_side="left",
        row_names_gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 8),
        
        column_title_gp=gpar(fontsize=10, fontface="bold"),
        column_title_rot=0,
        column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 20, fontface="bold"),
        row_dend_reorder = TRUE, column_dend_reorder = TRUE, clustering_method_rows = "complete",
        clustering_method_columns = "ward.D2", width = unit(100, "mm")
        )


decorate_heatmap_body("Z-score", {
  
  grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = "transparent", col = "black", lwd = 2))
  
})
```

I get something like this below image where apart from top few rows all looks like one big block. How do i make them look like each row a separate block.

My data used for the above plot

```
dput(heat)
structure(c(0.707106781186547, 0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186547, 
0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548, -0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548, 
-0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548, 
-0.707106781186547, 0.707106781186547, 0.707106781186546, 0.707106781186547, 
0.707106781186547, 0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186539, 
0.707106781186547, 0.707106781186546, 0.707106781186546, 0.707106781186548, 
0.707106781186547, 0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548, 
0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186547, 
0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186548, -0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548, 
-0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548, -0.707106781186547, 0.707106781186548, 
-0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186549, 
-0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186548, -0.707106781186548, 
-0.707106781186556, -0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186549, -0.707106781186549, 
-0.707106781186548, -0.707106781186547, -0.707106781186548, -0.707106781186547, 
-0.707106781186548, -0.707106781186548, -0.707106781186548), .Dim = c(29L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("ATP synthase subunit beta", "V-type proton ATPase subunit G, putative", 
"Vacuolar proton pump subunit B", "M17 leucyl aminopeptidase, putative", 
"H(+)-transporting two-sector ATPase", "L-lactate dehydrogenase", 
"Thioredoxin peroxidase 1", "Peroxiredoxin, putative", "Proteasome subunit alpha type-1, putative", 
"Proteasome subunit alpha type-2, putative", "Proteasome subunit alpha type-6, putative", 
"Proteasome subunit alpha type-5, putative", "Proteasome subunit beta type-7, putative", 
"Aminopeptidase P, putative", "Ras-related protein Rab-2, putative", 
"Protein phosphatase PPM2", "Protein phosphatase PPM8", "Kelch domain-containing protein, putative", 
"Plasmepsin IV", "Cytoadherence linked asexual protein, putative", 
"High molecular weight rhoptry protein 3, putative", "High molecular weight rhoptry protein 2", 
"Exported protein 1", "Exported protein 2", "Translocon component PTEX150", 
"Rhoptry neck protein 4", "Rhoptry associated adhesin, putative", 
"Rhoptry neck protein 6, putative", "Rhoptry neck protein 12"
), c("WT_Intensity", "AAT1_Intensity")), "`scaled:center`" = c(17.5323275756918, 
12.5879279763914, 7.5401414560253, 9.04624468845455, 8.56124374900428, 
19.6628733567755, 9.65500076513037, 15.7927947316372, 16.6030212709358, 
7.60569701604908, 8.56046802398039, 15.7666437893553, 5.23974867745572, 
14.0615197163815, 9.59489610029214, 7.78961966091922, 5.4857081174032, 
7.8005574871979, 21.9766899064477, 9.52031394237784, 17.8070206178665, 
17.0544410524523, 10.4575462036285, 16.9036711824594, 15.8482002898553, 
14.3776501925613, 8.99955981026985, 6.85652138529223, 8.43092140696476
), "`scaled:scale`" = c(0.535824438642248, 0.382830340883356, 
9.2491567469495, 11.3791083645849, 10.6932134582506, 5.14478947757017, 
12.2400194643969, 1.29280852741531, 0.64698164549907, 9.34186630902409, 
10.6921164174012, 1.80434443334261, 5.99591008071127, 0.80239530017384, 
3.16637672778425, 9.60197220782697, 6.34374925647869, 9.61744063009317, 
0.20290456563894, 12.0495435329873, 1.65362496030127, 1.43528282537116, 
13.3749901079416, 1.3729510404263, 1.01983825139877, 2.90545357044537, 
11.3130859766984, 8.28237197140834, 10.5089098346581))
>
```

[image: my image]

Suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: All rows have the same value so they have the same color, so I don't understand, how would you want to separate them ?

Comment: yes i saw it now ..i was just plotting the data so i didn't see that first , shall i go without scaling?

Comment: without scaling i got what i was looking for thanks for pointing it out